# How optimize sqlite query with dates & substr?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, performance, sqlite

I have some sqlite querys that are slowding my iPhone App.

I have 2 pattern that I repeat in my app. The first is with substr:

```
SELECT Id FROM [Table] WHERE UPPER(substr(Name,1,1))='A' ORDER BY Name"
```

(This run for the mayority of the alphabet. Is for a contact list)

The other is a complex one with date:

```
SELECT Id,customerCode, 
case
when DueDate>=datetime('now','-100 years') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','-1 days') then 'Past due'
when DueDate<datetime('now') then 'Today'
when DueDate>=datetime('now') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','15 days') then '15'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','16 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','30 days') then '30'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','31 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','45 days') then '45'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','46 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','60 days') then '60'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','61 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','90 days') then '90'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','91 days') then '> 90'
end As Key, 
COUNT(*) As Total, TimeStamp
FROM debt
GROUP BY customerCode,
case
when DueDate>=datetime('now','-100 years') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','-1 days') then '-1'
when DueDate<datetime('now') then 'Today'
when DueDate>=datetime('now') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','15 days') then '15'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','16 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','30 days') then '30'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','31 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','45 days') then '45'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','46 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','60 days') then '60'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','61 days') AND DueDate<=datetime('now','90 days') then '90'
when DueDate>=datetime('now','91 days') then '> 90'
end
```

In both case I have index for the date & the varchar field.

The 1st run ok in the simulator, and take 11 seconds in the iPod touch 2 GEN

The second query is slow too in the iPhone simulator (3 sec) & 1 min in the device. The dates are using the ISO date form.

I have tougth of build a cache table (and put trigers for the updates. The data is live and the user can modify it) for the data, but wonder if exist a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how the performance compares, but another way to write the first query there is

```
SELECT Id FROM [Table] WHERE Name LIKE "a%"
```

because a% matches any string beginning with a or A, followed by any number of characters.

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like for more reference.

Second, I'm guessing that you're taking a performance hit on repeated calls to datetime.  Can you compress it into a single mathematical operation, then compare the difference in days using simple mathematical operators?  For example, the number of days since last Christmas:

```
sqlite> select julianday('now') - julianday('2008-12-05');
212.743649386801
```

SQLite stores dates as strings internally, so every time you call `datetime` it has to fully parse the date string, etc.

Comment: With the LIKE the query spend 2 secs less.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to repeat that `CASE` operator twice -- just `GROUP BY CustomerCode, Key` will suffice. Also, as @Mark suggests, the `CASE` can be perhaps be optimized by using differences in julianday, and the name selection by exploiting the fact that `LIKE` is, by default, case insensitive (as long as you need ASCII letters only -- alas, it's a documented bug in sqlite that this case insensitivity doesn't work properly outside of ASCII).